# Saving Symbols in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i want to save the Symbols “, ” and — in a MySQL Database with PHP.

Thanks

Comment: ... do you want fries with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the problem.
Use prepared statements - they never interpolate values into mysql query. You should be able to save anything you want.

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    $calories = 150;
    $colour = 'red';
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
        FROM fruit
        WHERE calories < ? AND colour = ?');
    $sth->bindParam(1, $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->bindParam(2, $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
    $sth->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

always read php.net manual first:
PDO mysql manual:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Comment: Can you give me an example. Im not familiar with prepared statements.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "This contains a comma (,) and a quote (') and should break the query";
$quoted = mysql_real_escape_string($str); /// nyah nyah now it won't.
```